# Move ImageView in EditText?

Tags: android

I've an ImageView in EditText, how can I move down imageview when typing in edittext, and how can i add imageview after cursor when i pressed "enter" key?

Thanks!

```
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        mEditPost.setSelection(mEditPost.getText().length());

         if (s.length() > 0 && s.subSequence(s.length()-1, s.length()).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("\n")) {

         } else if (count == 0) {
             _send.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_send_disable);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked into TranslateAnimation classes using setFillAfter(true)? You should be able to accomplish it like that

Comment: ImageView in EditText? Not possible, EditText is not a ViewGroup. Did you mean something else?